# Webkit-appearance menulist not working on mobile view

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have a select list and it appears with a dropdown when viewed as a full browser. Then when viewing the same in the mobile view of the browser, it does not appear. I noticed the dropdown is added by the webkit-appearance: menulist.

Is there a reason why this is not working in smaller size screens. 
Note that when i just resize the screen, it still appears, but not when i view it in mobile view from inspect element.

Comment: did you figure this out?